# Changing background image of react app based on component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, background-image

I have googled around and tried various solutions but cannot seem to get my app to work correctly. I want my app to show a different background image based on what component is rendered on the screen. I am implementing this app with React Router and all styling is done with Material UI.

As suggested in other similar posts, I have tried to import the background images to each component class individually and use className's to render the background image (attempt shown below). However, when I try the solution below, I can't seem to get any background image to render. In fact, the only way I can get any background image to render is via my App.css code below. Doing this however sets a constant background image for the entire app, which leaves me back at square one.

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router history={history}>
          <NavBar />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the next two code segments show my attempt at showing different background images based on the component rendered.

**Home.js**

```
import image from "../relative/path.jpeg";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  home_scene: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
  },
}));

const Home = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.home_scene}>
     .... a lot of code here, left out for readability 
    </div>
```

**Contact.js**

```
import image from "../different/image's/relative/path.jpeg";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  contact_scene: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
  },
}));

const Contact = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.contact_scene}>
     .... a lot of code here, left out for readability 
    </div>
```

When attempting this, I fail to get any background image at all. The only way I can get any background image to show is by doing the following, which leaves one static background throughout the whole app.

**App.css**

```
body {
  background: url(/path/to/file) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Perhaps there is a way to render a background image with react router based on the current route, but I am not sure how to do that either. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

You can use React Router's useLocation hook to get the current url and set the background image based on that.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation